# Vertica's LISTAGG() Big Query Equivalent

Tags: google-bigquery, vertica

While migrating Vertica run reports to BQ, I stumbled upon a Vertica pre-built function LISTAGG().

What is the equivalent on Big Query?

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this

**Vertica:**
LISTAGG(column,'delimiter')

**Big Query:**
STRING_AGG(column,'delimiter')

Make sure to CAST(column as STRING) in case Vertica's column is from INT